# Map project folder in PhpStorm

Tags: php, apache, wamp, phpstorm

The path to local project folder is `C:\Users\user\PhpstormProjects\postest\` and the path to WAMP is `C:/wamp`.

I want to run my project from its directory using WAMP. I've tried mapping the projects folder but it displays "file not found" on running.

In the mappings settings local path is set to `C:\Users\user\PhpstormProjects\postest\` and deployment and web path to `postest`.

How can I execute the project?

Comment: Why are you trying to run a php project from other directories rather than from server directory [in your case `C:\wamp\www`]?. If it's there any specific reason please edit your question and mention it.

Comment: 1) Deployments in PhpStorm: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm 2) Installing and configuring XAMPP (yes, it's not WAMP but have very similar ideas, at least for your issue): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618